# Google Play Developer API | Reply to Reviews

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth, google-play-developer-api

POST

```
https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/{your_package_name}/reviews/
{review_id}:reply?access_token={your_access_token}
```

Header : { Content-Type:application/json }

Body : { "replyText" : "comment_having_306_characters_no_html_tags" }

However, I get the following response from google

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [{
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "invalid",
            "message": "Invalid Value"
        }],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid Value"
    }
}
```

According to google developer portal "The request failed because it contained an invalid value. The value could be a parameter value, a header value, or a property value." 
Can anyone here enlighten me on what's wrong with the value i passed in ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: While retrieving reviews from google play store somebody was getting same error response. Previous discussion on this error message :[https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-apis-explorer-users/sJ5glcRva_s/MJb8W67yQEsJ]

Comment: Without details of your precise call it is unlikely someone can help you, and you don't want to give those parameters in a public forum like Stack Overflow. This is a question your are better off contacting Google Play support. You can contact them using the help menu on the Play Console, behind the "?" icon. Then you can share your exact Parameters